# Realm Migration for Column type long

Tags: android, realm, realm-migration

I have created a new long field in my `RealmModel` class and I have to migrate the existing schema. But as it turn out there is no `ColumnType.LONG`. When I use any other ColumnType I get -

```
JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: input is not valid Modified UTF-8: illegal continuation byte 0x2e
11-20 11:55:40.019 17835-17952/com.my.app A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]     string: 'Unrecoverable error. Failure when converting long string to UTF-16 error_code = 2; retcode = 0; StringData.size = 8188713; StringData.data =
```

Answer (score 1):

The underlying storage engine only have one Integer type called: `ColumnType.INTEGER`, it will automatically adapt itself to the size of the input, so using that should be fine.

Comment: Still getting the same error - `D/REALM: jni: ThrowingException 11, Failure when converting long string to UTF-16 error_code = 2; retcode = 0; StringData.size = 8188713;`

Comment: The errors you are getting is about Strings, not integers. Is there a chance you are working on a field that contains Strings instead of integers?

Comment: I have an existing realm file in which I want to add a column `Table wordTable = realm.getTable(WordModel.class);
            wordTable.addColumn(ColumnType.INTEGER, "timestringLong");` and this is the field I added in my `WordModel` class `private long timestringLong;`

Comment: That sounds right. It is probably easier to create an issue on GitHub so we can investigate further: https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues